# switch virtualization for 802.1x?

Tags: virtualization, freeradius, wpa-supplicant

Here the thing :
I want to set a EAP-TLS 802.1x connexion with Freeradius.
The freeradius server is on a vm, the host is the client.
The thing is that I didn't have Wi-fi or internet connexion on my machine (no box! nothing).
So I wanted to use a virtual switch for the 802.1x part.
After some research, I found OpenVSwitch but it doesn't have 802.1x feature :(

The client : 
- my physical computer (the client have to be this machine)
- ubuntu 14.04 desktop
- wpa_supplicant

The server : 
- a vm created with qemu/kvm (virt-manager)
- ubuntu 14.04 desktop
- freeradius

I have make a connexion (a bridge) between the vm and the host (the client) :
client  : eth0 192.168.0.4 - br0 192.168.0.3
vmserveur : eth0 192.168.0.5

Thanks!
Ju

Comment: Here's the thing - this question is off-topic for [SO] because it isn't a programming related question.

Comment: The only way you might be able to do this, is using hostapd if it can operate on a wired interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember right I finally used GNS3 with an ISO Cisco router. 
thanks.